# Website swipe content move

Tags: web, touch, swipe

I'm trying to develop a Windows Phone interface-like feature - using horizontal swipe to the right to display a menu.
Basically I have two 100 % width columns, one of which is pushed to the right and therefore invisible. How can I implement a animated swipe, that would allow the interaction I want? How can I make the horizontal Scroll animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web or native?
If you're making web I suggest using *** http://quojs.tapquo.com/ ***